# Label font size

Tags: graphics, libgdx, kotlin

I want add to stage a label with specified font size.

```
val label = Label("label", Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json")))
label.height = 20f
stage.addActor(label)
```

Changing label.height does not works, label is shown with some default size.
So the question is how to set label font size?

Comment: Label.setFontScale()

Answer (score 0):

You can do only:

`label.setFontScale(5.0f)`

Also, you can specify font size in font file. It's the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Try either [setSize](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setSize-float-float-) `label.setSize(width, height)` or [setScale](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setScale-float-) `label.setScale(xyScaleFactor)`